# Profiling application on Python in production

Tags: python, profiling

I have a question about profiling an application in production which works in Docker container. I'm trying to use py-spy but it doesn't work.

When I try to simply use:

I was trying

```
py-spy record -o profile.svg -- python3 app.py
```

I've got this error:

> Python Error: Failed to get process executable name. Check that the process is running

But my app is working.
Can somebody suggest me some app for profiling my app?